# I need help using Scilab to average an 100x100x100 matrix in 2x2x2 cubes

Tags: math, matrix, average, scilab

I am using Scilab to average an 100x100x100 matrix in 2x2x2 cubes.How can I change this script so that it averages it in 9x9x9 cubes?I know 100^3 doesn't divide evenly into 9x9x9 cubes.I just want to average it until it can no longer be evenly diveded.

`a=1
    b=1
    c=1
    numbers = rand(100,100,100)
    while c <=99,
    if a>99 then
            a=1
            b=b+2
        c=1;
        end
    if b>99 then
        a=1
        b=1
        c=c+2;
        end
    average=(numbers(a,b,c)+numbers(a+1,b,c)+numbers(a,b+1,c)+numbers(a+1,b+1,c)                                    +numbers(a,b,c+1)+numbers(a+1,b,c+1)+numbers (a,b+1,c+1)+numbers(a+1,b+1,c+1))/8

    a=(a+2);
    end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [matrix function](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.0/en_US/mean.html) that is built into scilab. Simply use this at each iteration with cubes of the desired size.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you want but:

```
mean(numbers(1:9, 1:9, 1:9))
```

is probably what you need.